# Redirect any requests for a php file to site root?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess

I'm attempting to redirect any requests for a PHP file to the site root, is there any way to do this? We performed a large site upgrade but we want to prevent errors caused by people being referred from old links from Google.

I had attempted to use the following, but it's causing a few issues with our system.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php /
```

We've tried numerous similar ideas, has anyone got a better one (that works)? :D

Update: I forgot to mention that the system we use uses mod_rewrite to direct SEO-friendly URLs to pages. Theoretically there are no direct .php file references in a correct URL. The problem with the above solution is that it seems to bugger up a couple of our scripts, though I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

If these pages are going to return a 404 error page, you can simply override the 404 error page and make it a meta redirect to the home page. This would capture not only files ending in .php but any page which doesn't exist, I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I did actually try doing it that way before I realised that wrong URLs didn't actually produce a 404, but an XSL compile error in the software (we use Symphony CMS). It might be a good plan to drop the redirect into compile error pages, as we don't want people to see those anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Much as I love mod_rewrite, in this case you might want to try mod_alias instead:

```
    <Location />
            DirectoryIndex index.html
    </Location>
    RedirectMatch permanent \.php$ /
```